# What reason have the designers given for why minimum hit die size is d6?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, hit-points, designer-reasons

In D&D 3rd edition and also D20 I remember some hit points for classes being well below 1D6 per level (especially for wizards and the like).

Still though Pathfinder surprised me that it went with 1D6 as minimum for each class. I'm wondering there though if there is any reason stated by the designers for this change so that 1D6 is the minimum for each level in the classes?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63290/discussion-on-question-by-thomas-e-is-there-any-reason-known-why-pathfinder-swi).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Several sources](http://dictionary.sensagent.com/Pathfinder%20Roleplaying%20Game/en-en/) quote Jason Buhlman (Pathfinder lead designer) as explaining the change is part of improvements to the game designed to improve survivability at low levels.

> For example the Wizard as well as the Sorcerer now have a d6 instead of d4 as their Hit-Dice improving the survivability of these classes in low level games

I can't find the original source document they reference, "Paizo Publishing Announces the Pathfinder RPG" from 2008, but I have no reason to believe it's inaccurate. That was initially a blog post so it's probably trying to point to some article somewhere on the Paizo blog, but it may not still be extant.

Comment: I found "[Paizo Publishing® Announces the *Pathfinder RPG™*](http://paizo.com/paizo/news/archive/2008/v5748eaic9l3h?Paizo-Publishing-Announces-the-Pathfinder-RPGTM)" (2008), but the attributed quotes  (on second thought, I think maybe they're paraphrases, not direct quotes) aren't in there. I think that article's source-footnotes are probably misplaced and those statements are from a different source. Despite that I recall this being the reasons given at the time, but it seems like it will be hard to track down statements now.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Maybe the wayback machine?